# Extra text being added to Repeater field Label

Tags: .net, text, internet-explorer-8

This is only happening in IE8 (I don't have IE7 or IE9 to test on). In firefox it looks fine.

I have a repeater that is displaying different types of logos read from the database. It displays a checkbox, logo image, and the name of the type of logo. Easy enough.

Here is the .NET code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptLogos" runat="server" DataSourceID="ShirtLogos">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="logos">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="checkBoxLogo" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("intID") %>' />
            <asp:Label ID="Label13" AssociatedControlID="checkBoxLogo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("strName") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# "~/Images/Logos/" + Eval("strFileName") %>' runat="server" />                                                          
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The reason I don't use the CheckBox Text is because I need full control over the layout with the styles. Anyway the html behind the scenes doesn't show it. It's only when it's rendered to the page. The text will read as follows:

> Full Color Logo ogo

It should be

> Full Color Logo

Where is that extra "ogo" coming from?

I tried inserting just a general "Test" as the text. And I got

> Test est

No where in the page source is it showing up. What could be causing this weird behavior?

Comment: I resorted to using the asp:CheckBox TEXT="" call to fix the issue. What a weird situation. Anyway, just fix the styles to accomodate the different layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to using the asp:CheckBox TEXT="" call to fix the issue. What a weird situation. Anyway, just fix the styles to accomodate the different layout.